# How do you use datepicker to display data into fullcalendar

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, fullcalendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY8Gl.png)
So let me explain the flow of my function.

1. Go to index.jsp (Calendar page)
2. click the '+' button on the date you want to add an event
3. goes to AddEvent.jsp
4. Fill in the form> Data entered in the form must be able to display in the specific cell that    you clicked to add event. For example if you click on 12th March    2017's cell, the data you entered in AddEvent.jsp should be able to    display in that specific cell. I have a datepicker in AddEvent.jsp so now the problem is, how do I set my fullcalendar to display data according to the date i pick in my jsp page using a datepicker.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@page import="model.AddEvents,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.ListIterator" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();



    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        },




});

</script>
    <title>Calendar</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <a class= "add_event_label" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea"></a>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <h1>Calendar</h1>

                <br />

                <div id="bootstrapModalFullCalendar"></div>




            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

  <!-- this is the pop up window when you press the button -->

   <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>

                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>

                </div>

                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">


                 </div>


                <!-- <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a>

                </div>-->

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {

                    left: '',

                    center: 'prev title next',

                    right: ''


                },
                //action after calendar loaded
                eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
                    if(view.name == 'month')
                    {                       
                        //loop all .fc-day elements
                        $('.fc-day').each(function(){
                        //jQuery styling
                            $(this).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': '100%'});
                            $(this).css('position','relative');
                            //add elements to each .fc-day, you can modify the content in append() with your own html button code
                            $(this).append('<a class="add_event_label" href ="AddEvent.jsp" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;display:block;font-size:12px;color:blue;cursor:pointer;">(+)</a>' );
                            <%!ArrayList<AddEvents> myEventList; //have to declear in a declaration tag for access in the page %>
                            <% myEventList = (ArrayList<AddEvents>) request.getAttribute("EventList");
                            if(myEventList.size() == 0)
                            {
                                %>
                                <h2>No events</h2>
                                <%
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                %>


                            <%
                            ListIterator<AddEvents> li = myEventList.listIterator();

                            while(li.hasNext())
                            {
                                AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();
                                myEvent= (AddEvents)li.next();
                                %>

                            $(this).append('<p>Title:</p><p><%= myEvent.getTitle() %></p></p>');
                            <%}


                                %>

                                <%
                                }
                                %>



                        });      
                    }                   
                },

                eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    //$(".fc-day-number").prepend("(+) ");

                    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);

                    $('#modalBody').html(event.description);

                    $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);

                    $('#fullCalModal').modal();

                    return false;

                }


            })
            })

    </script>
    </body>
<input id='eventID' type="hidden" name="hiddEvent" value="">
</html>
```

RetrieveServlet: It's the controller and the main page that I run to display the index.jsp

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DBAO;
import model.AddEvents;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RetrieveServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RetrieveServlet")
public class RetrieveServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RetrieveServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());


        doPost(request,response); //dispatcher sents deget request, since ur code is in dopost, u will need to all it.
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        {
            DBAO myDatabase = new DBAO();
            ArrayList <AddEvents> myEventList = myDatabase.getAddEvents();
            System.out.println(myEventList.size());
            request.setAttribute("EventList",myEventList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Accessing Database:" +ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

What it does now is display all the data in mysql database in all of the cells. I would greatly appreciate if you guys help. I tried searching online but there is nothing regarding this and I modified how actually a fullcalendar works. If I'm not wrong fullcalendar works by dragging and dropping the events but I'm dealing with a more complex thing. I've added a picture on the flow for better understanding.
You guys can also refer to this -https://fullcalendar.io/docs/ to understand full calendar better. Hope you guys understand it and thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$('.fc-day').each(function(){` - in this loop you go through all the days on the calendar and append all your events to each day. I don't understand why you would do this? Why not just bind your events as shown in the documentation - either https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ depending on your exact situation

Comment: @ADyson I don't know how it works and my project requires me to only use jsp,servlet,jQuery/ajax and java. Nothing else

Comment: you can use both of those methods with the technologies just listed. No problem. You can understand how it works from the fullCalendar side by reading those articles. In the most basic one (events as JSON) you give fullCalendar a URL as the "events" property. When the calendar loads, and whenever you change the date or view, it uses ajax to call that URL, passing in the current start/end dates, and downloads the latest event data from the response. It expects the event data in the response from that URL to be in the JSON format understood by fullCalendar, and cover only the dates specified...

Comment: ...you can easily write some Java code to create an endpoint which will accept those parameters, query your database, and return the data as JSON - it looks like you already have the database code and you can easily google how to make it into JSON, you just have to provide that functionality accessible as a separate URL away from your main page's URL. I don't know JSP so can't help you with specifics but that is the general design you need to follow. The way you're doing it at the moment is bizarre and will never work properly.

Comment: @ADyson I just added a date input in my AddEvents.jsp. Will that work tot connect my datepicker to append each cell in my fullcalendar?

Comment: You haven't said what you want it to do when you click on the datepicker? And how is that related to setting up your event feed properly in fullCalendar, as we were discussing? BTW there's no need for you to append events directly to the fullCalendar cells - fullCalendar handles that automatically for you when you set up your events feed properly. And if you want to allow the user to add a new event via the UI then you can call the "renderEvent" method https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ and pass the event object as JSON, and fullCalendar will attach it for you correctly

Comment: @ADyson The datepicker displays data to the date in fullcalendar (date cell). Ok I will try that ^